# How to develop custom task (in autoplugin) that would be called from command line?

Tags: sbt

I started having a look at sbt plugins, I have this class:

```scala
package msbt.test.plugin

import sbt._
import Keys._

object SbtTest extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")
  }

  import autoImport._
  hello := println("hello world")
}
```

I would like to call the task from command line. How can I add this to my `Build.scala`? I cannot reach the package from there:

```scala
import sbt._
import msbt.test.plugin._ // this cannot be resolved

object SbtGitBuild extends Build {}
```

It does work of course if I add it manually to the build file or to the `build.sbt` file like this:

```scala
sbtPlugin := true

name := "sbt-test-plugin"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")

hello := println("hello world!")
```

And then from the console I can call `hello`, but of course what I would like is to be able to structure my code and avoid having to throw it inside the build file. Is this possible? Do I need another sbt project which imports my plugin to use and test it? If so which is the fastest way?

Since I'm a beginner I write and test every piece of code, It would be nice to have a fast way to include updates into another project.

[Here](https://github.com/EndeNeu/SbtPluginTest) the link to the Github repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your setting in one of the setting sequences that are included in the project, like `project/SbtTest.scala`:

```scala
package msbt.test.plugin

import sbt._
import Keys._
import File

object SbtTest extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")
  }

  import autoImport._
  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    hello := println("hello world")
  )
}
```

In addition, you've created an autoplugin which is *explicitly* enabled.  So you'll need to also enable the plugin in your `project/build.scala`:

```scala
import sbt._
import msbt.test.plugin._ // this cannot be resolved

object SbtGitBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).enablePlugins(SbtTest)
}
```

*or* you need to override the `trigger` method to be

```scala
override def trigger = allRequirements
```

The scaladoc for the AutoPlugin class is quite good, although the formatting is bad:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.AutoPlugin

or

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/Plugins.scala.html

Comment: I tried both approachs but neither of them worked, adding this `.enablePlugins(SbtTest)` gives me a compile error because the `SbtTest` cannot be found (nor can I import the package where it's defined) while for the trigger, I'm unsure of what to do, I tried with `allRequirments` but still sbt cannot find the command.

Comment: You may need to send more of your build for help.

Comment: I added a link to the git repository with all the code.

Comment: Ok, (1) The `lazy val project` line should be in your `build.sbt` file

Comment: (2) you can't use a plugin you're defining in the project unless you've previously released it and can depend on the binary.  If it's a part of your build.  SO, sbt legitimately cannot find the plugin because you haven't told the build about it.

Comment: For (2) you can move the plugin into `project/src/main/scala/` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I wish it was possible to test it without having to go through the releasing process and so on, moving the plugin in `project/src/main/scala/` and moving the `lazy val root` (I guess you mispelled it since I have no `lazy val project`) to the `build.sbt` file didn't worked as hoped (the `SbtTest` is still not visible).