# Is there any working example of sbt plugin which defined with AutoPlugin?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I see there is a `AutoPlugin` feature in sbt 0.13.5 version, and want to define a simple sbt plugin with it.

But sadly, I followed the document(which is not in detail) also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234451/how-to-develop-custom-task-in-autoplugin-that-would-be-called-from-command-lin) which is not actually resolved, without any lucky.

Is there any working example I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the key to making this work was the line `override val trigger = allRequirements`. I found it deep within a scaladays presentation on SBT, not in the SBT documentation.

Here's [the Plugin source](https://github.com/Synesso/sbt-spg/blob/9381a940260fea47c7fd3c1f123080623b7f8b2f/src/main/scala/sbtspg/SPGPlugin.scala).

In any other project I need only add the dependency to project/plugins.sbt to get the task enabled. e.g. `addSbtPlugin("com.github.synesso" % "sbt-spg" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")`

The statement `override val trigger = allRequirements` apparently means "enable the plugin when all requirements are met" and because I've not overridden `allRequirements` it defaults to meaning zero requirements. (It's all very odd if you ask me).